I want to use torch DataLoader and use producer/consumer pattern but it stucks
I want to change torch DataLoader, and use consumer/producer pattern inside it.
I have a queue that one thread puts files into it, and those items consumed using __getitem__ by framework.
here is my code:
import glob
import time
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import threading
import queue




class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    size = 25
    def __init__(self):
        self.voices_path = "/home/hatef/mmm/data/voice/"
        file_list = glob.glob(self.voices_path + "*")
        self.data = []
        for f in file_list:
            self.data.append(f)
        self.q = queue.Queue(CustomDataset.size)

    def fill_queue(self):
        dataz = self.data
        it = 0
        while it < len(dataz):
            path = dataz[it]
            if not self.q.full():
                with open(path,"rb") as f:
                    self.q.put(f.read())
                    it += 1
            else:
                print("queue size: " + str(self.q.qsize()))
                time.sleep(2)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, _):
        print("before get item")
        item = self.q.get()
        self.q.task_done()
        return [item, 1]
 

    
params = {'batch_size': 16,
          'shuffle': True,
          'num_workers': 4}


epoch = 100


dataset = CustomDataset()
training_generator = DataLoader(dataset, **params)

producer = threading.Thread(target=dataset.fill_queue, daemon=True)
producer.start()

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(epoch):
    for f in training_generator:
        print(f) 
        print("............")
    print(f"**********************************run epoch***************************************: {i}")
# time.sleep(10)
end_time = time.time()

execution_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} seconds")


   

__getitem__ never progresses in my code. what is the problem?
